# Add customer field in openerp pos module

Tags: module, field, odoo

I am using openerp 6.1.Here in pos module there is no feature of selecting customer.I want to add this field.But i couldn't.Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra fields by inheriting any model in your customized module.

You have to inherit the "pos.order" object & view.

Inherit 'pos.order' in your .py:

```
class pos_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'pos.order'
    _columns = {
        'customer_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer'),
    }
pos_order()
```

Above code will create a field in your database.

Now, To display your field in your form, inherit the view of 'pos.order'  in your .xml,:

```
<record id="inherited_form_pos_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">pos.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">pos.order</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_pos_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <field name="name" position="after">
                  <field name="customer_id"/>
              </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Now, you can see "Customer" field in your pos.order form.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.According to you it adds field in openerp Backend.But i need to add customer in point of sale module that is only visible in browser.That's xml is in /addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/pos.xml.Frankly speaking i am able to add a button named customer.But i am unable to create button action.If possible plz help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: What you actually want to do? If you want to display field in view, you have to write it in xml. Can you provide your code or more information?

Comment: I think she wants to have a search button filter.  Priyanka pls shed some light

Comment: yes.u r rit Vishal.i want to search customer from res_partner table.That is happen in pos backend.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its already there then what's your issue? Can you please specify your problem/issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to add this in Point Of sale where product images are viewed.

Comment: For that you have to make changes in web addons. I mean in pos module, coding for web is written. So you have to make changes in that.

Comment: to do that i have to change /openerp/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/pos.xml file.But i couldn't do that.if possible plz give me some hints.i think to do this java script is needed.